# grape share rails activerecord-session_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-grape, grape-api

I want to use session of Rails activerecord-session_store in grape-api.
But `env['rack.session'][:foo]` in the below code is null.
Please tell me how to resolve.

```
class API < Grape::API
    use ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
    ~~
    get :ping do
        p env['rack.session'][:foo]
        env['rack.session'][:foo] = "bar"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails sessions hate symbols, you can put symbols in, but getting the value you always have to use a string, so try `session['foo']`

I use a grape helper method by the way to access the session as `session` which is actually `env['rack.session']`

By the way, if you want to reuse your rails session don't forget to set the name to the same name as your rails session cookie:

```
use ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore, key: '_appname_session'
```